# Do citizens of the Philippines need a visa to visit South Korea?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens

I'm an Australian permanent resident holding a Philippines passport and I am planning to go on a holiday to South Korea for 10 days. Do I need to apply for a visa? My passport has my return visa attached on it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=AU&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KR&selDest=Korea%28Rep.%29%2C%20South&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Philippines with a
>   residence permit issued by Australia if in transit through
>   Korea (Rep.), holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>   30 days, when:
>
> -arriving from Australia, departing to a third country (e.g.
>   SYD-ICN-PVG); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country, departing to Australia (e.g.
>   PVG-ICN-SYD); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country after having transited that
>   country for a maximum stay of 3 days, departing to Australia
>   (e.g. PVG-SGN-ICN-SYD); **or**
>
> -arriving from a third country, traveling to another country
>   and staying there for a maximum stay of 3 days, then departing
>   to Australia (e.g. PVG-ICN-SGN-SYD).

So if you **don't** fly direct in **both** directions, but make a stopover at least in one direction, you do **not** need a visa for max 30 days.

Otherwise, you **do** need a visa

Answer (score 1):

Your passport is what matters, so unless you have Official/Diplomat passport, you will need to apply for Tourist visa.

> > [Korea Immigration Service Visa Navigator](http://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10101)
> >
> > Settings: Asia>Philippines>Short Term Visit>90 days or less
>
> Visa Exempted(B-1): A person with a diplomatic or official passport of Philippines can visit Korea without a visa and stay for any desired period under the Visa Exemption Agreement between the two countries.
>
> ---
>
> Ordinary Tourist(C-3-9): A person who plans to visit Korea on the purpose of travel for holidays or leisure

Comment: Not completely correct

Comment: How so? Any other proof?

Comment: See my answer..